# Does the "before" hook trigger a render when leveraging transition hooks in a render function?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to create a movement transition within a render function using appear hooks.  I thought that putting initial state of the transition within the `beforeAppear` hook and then setting the finalized state in the `appear` hook would cause an element to be enough for a transition to occur.

However, what seems to be happening is that the style that I set in the `beforeAppear` either never renders, or is overwritten in the `appear` hook before the browser knows that it should transition.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.  Using `Vue.nextTick()` does not give me what I was hoping.  However, I do see that using a `setTimeout()` will give me what I am effectively looking for, but I thought that this was the built-in functionality of the `appear` hook considering the docs [Transition Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes):

> 1. `v-enter`: Starting state for enter. Added before element is inserted, removed one frame after element is inserted.
> 2. `v-enter-active`: Active state for enter. Applied during the entire entering phase. Added before element is inserted, removed when
>    transition/animation finishes. This class can be used to define the
>    duration, delay and easing curve for the entering transition.

I understand that these are for the **classes** that are applied to the element, but don't these map 1:1 with the hooks?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h) {

    // Just hooks
    const transitionTestJustHooks = h("transition", {
      props: {
        css: false,
        appear: ""
      },
      on: {
        beforeAppear(el) {
          console.log("before-appear");
          el.style.position = "absolute";
          el.style.transition = "left 2s ease";
          el.style.top = "0em";
          el.style.left = "20px";
        },
        appear(el, done) {
          console.log("appear");
          el.style.left = "200px";
          done();
        }
      }
    }, [h("div", "just-hooks")]);

    // Vue.nextTick()
    const transitionTestNextTick = h("transition", {
      props: {
        css: false,
        appear: ""
      },
      on: {
        beforeAppear(el) {
          console.log("before-appear");
          el.style.position = "absolute";
          el.style.transition = "left 2s ease";
          el.style.top = "1em";
          el.style.left = "20px";
        },
        appear(el, done) {
          console.log("appear");
          Vue.nextTick(() => {
            el.style.left = "200px";
            done();
          });
        }
      }
    }, [h("div", "Vue.nextTick()")]);

    // setTimeout()
    const transitionTestSetTimeout = h("transition", {
      props: {
        css: false,
        appear: ""
      },
      on: {
        beforeAppear(el) {
          console.log("before-appear");
          el.style.position = "absolute";
          el.style.transition = "left 2s ease";
          el.style.top = "2em";
          el.style.left = "20px";
        },
        appear(el, done) {
          console.log("appear");
          setTimeout(() => {
            el.style.left = "200px";
            done();
          });
        }
      }
    }, [h("div", "setTimeout")]);

    return h("div", [
      transitionTestJustHooks,
      transitionTestNextTick,
      transitionTestSetTimeout
    ]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```